# using geopy to find the country name from coordinates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I am trying to determine the country name for each row in a `pandas` dataframe using `geopy`. What I have is:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

df = pd.DataFrame({'ser_no': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                'lat': [53.57, 35.52, 35.53, 54.66, 54.67, 55.8],
                'lon': [-117.20, -98.29, -98.32, -119.48, -119.47, -119.46]})

def get_country(locations):
    locations = geolocator.reverse(row['lat'], row['lon'], timeout = 10)
    for location in locations:
        for component in location.raw['address_components']:
            if 'country' in component['types']:
                return component['long_name']

my_key = my_api_key                   
geolocator = GoogleV3(my_key, proxies ={"http": 'my proxy',
                                        "https": 'my proxy'})

df['country'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_country(row), axis = 1)
```

This returns

```
     lat     lon  ser_no                                       country
0  53.57 -117.20       1  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
1  35.52  -98.29       1  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
2  35.53  -98.32       1  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
3  54.66 -119.48       2  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
4  54.67 -119.47       2  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
5  55.80 -119.46       2  <function get_country at 0x000000000F6F9C88>
```

No errors have occurred but my output isn't useful. I am not sure if it just returning incorrectly or if I have something wrong in my `apply`.

Comment: shouldn't your function signature be `row` rather than `locations`?

Comment: `get_country(locations)` should be `get_country(row)`?

Comment: How about changing to this: `df['country'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_country(row), axis = 1)` shouldn't make a difference but it's explicit here

Comment: @EdChum by changing the function argument to row and explicitly stating get_country(row), I get the following `ValueError: ('Invalid point', u'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: On which line as it looks like your error has progressed now

Comment: If you manually entered those numbers does it work?  `geolocator.reverse(53.57, -117.20, timeout = 10)`

Comment: The docs seems to state that you're supposed to pass a string:https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/

Comment: Try `geolocator.reverse(str(row['lat']) + ', ' + str(row['lon']), timeout = 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`geolocator.reverse`](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/) takes a string so you need to change your function to this:

```
def get_country(row):
    pos = str(row['lat']) + ', ' + str(row['lon'])
    locations = geolocator.reverse(pos, timeout = 10)
    #... rest of func the same
```